# Sencha Touch 2 : How to determine that application is idle?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am handling session management with Sencha touch 2. I want to show the session-timeout message if the application is idle for x minutes.

I think of implementing it such a way that if any events happened on the application then capture it so it can be concluded that application is not idle.

How can I observe the events across the application? I think Observable method can be helpful in this scenario. Any suggetions plz?

Thank you
Gendaful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it the following way by capturing the touchstart, touchend and touchmove events on the body.

```
var docBody = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
docBody.addEventListener('touchstart touchend touchmove', function () {

alert(' Event has happened');

}
```

Thanks